# XML reading Data with Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

For each instrumentData in the below XML file, I need to print the id and the values in the data value=" " field. (the value between the quotes) All this using python 2.7

This is my XML file:

```
<instrumentDatas>
  <instrumentData>
    <instrument>
    <id>Stephan</id>
  </instrument>
  <data value="A" />
  <data value="B" />
  <data value="C" />
</instrumentData>
<instrumentData>
  <instrument>
   <id>Patrick</id>
  </instrument>
  <data value="F" />
  <data value="G" />
  <data value="H" />
</instrumentData>
```

I am able to print the id for each instrumentData with the below code but cant figure out how to print the values.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc=minidom.parse("C:/Users/Desktop/PythonXMLproject/Smallfile.xml")

instrumentDatas = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("instrumentDatas")[0]
instrumentDatax= instrumentDatas.getElementsByTagName("instrumentData")

for instrumentData in instrumentDatax:
     idx=instrumentData.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.data
     print(idx)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("C:/Users/Desktop/PythonXMLproject/Smallfile.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

instrumentDatas = collection.getElementsByTagName("instrumentData")

for instrumentData in instrumentDatas:
    idx = instrumentData.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.data
    print "ID: %s" % idx 
    datas = instrumentData.getElementsByTagName("data")
    for data in datas:
        if data.hasAttribute('value'):
            value = data.getAttribute('value')
            print "Value: %s" % value
```